# Why is $(S_n)^2 - n(q-p)$ a martingale for a random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

If we have a random walk such that 
$$P(S_{n+1} = S_n + 1|S_n)=p$$ and $$P(S_{n+1} = S_n - 1|S_n)= 1-p=q$$
then why is $$(S_n)^2 - n(q-p)$$ a martingale.

I understand that $(S_n)^2$ is a sub-martingale but why do we take away $n(q-p)$ to get a martingale?

In the symmetric random walk case I understand this would be $(S_n)^2 - n$, but again I can't understand this inutition behind this.

Comment: Actually, $(S_n)^2 - n(q-p)$ is **not** a martingale.

Comment: You'd first need to take away the correct mean of $S_n^2$, which is $n(q-p)+npq$ (the mean of $S_n$ plus the variance of $S_n$). This is because a martingale has constant expectation. It is then an interesting question whether just subtracting off the deterministic mean is enough to get a martingale. It's difficult to get intuition for why this should be the case; I usually find it easier to just do the calculation.

Comment: @Did. Yep sorry, I was tired and made a mistake in my question.

Comment: @Ian thank you very much for your answer. That helped me understand it